# SCRIPT5009: “$” is undefined in IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

There is

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined

document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'><\/script>");

 var $jQueyobject = $;
```

with jQuery 1.10.2 in IE7 & IE8 . Why '$' is undefined in IE7 & IE8 ?

it working fine in chrome & FF

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want to write your `<script>` tag via `document.write` ? You don't even give time for the script to load.

Comment: Presumably the script hasn't finished loading before you try and use it

Comment: If you check the source with F12 Dev Tools (in IE8), can you see the script?

Answer (score 3):

This is a 'security' feature, intended to stop script injection.

The workaround is to concatenate parts of the `script` tag string together. Try this:

```
document.write("<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></scr" + "ipt>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The newly created `script` tag is added *after* the `script` tag wherein you create the new one. Hence `$` will be `undefined`. You need to separate your code into two `script` tags:

```
<script>
    document.write("<script...><\/script>");
</script>
<script>
    var $jQueyobject = $;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure all script loaded first and put it inside  html tag.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```